# character device driver's offset in read operation

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

```
static ssize_t read(struct file *file, char  *buff, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "write\n");
    return    simple_read_from_buffer(buff, len, offset, ker_buff, SIZE);
}

static ssize_t write(struct file *file, const char  *buff, size_t len, loff_t *offset)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "read\n");
    printk(KERN_INFO "your offset is:%lu\n",(long)offset);

    return      simple_write_to_buffer(ker_buff, SIZE, offset, buff, len);
}
```

when I perform `echo "hi" > /dev/device_name` I am getting output:

```
read
your offset is 0 as output.`
```

Why am I getting 0?

In man page its mentioned as user's offset position.

Can any one explain me what is the use of  offset?

Comment: You are printing an *address*! Try printing `*offset` instead of `(long)offset`.

Comment: would you expect some different value for the `offset`?

Comment: Are you really printing `(long)offset` and not `(long)*offset`? If so, it appears that the `offset` pointer is `NULL`, but that should only be the case if the driver's `open` file handler calls `stream_open()`. It should be noted that `simple_read_from_buffer()` and `simple_write_to_buffer()` dereference the `offset` pointer unconditionally, so that would result in a kernel Oops if `offset` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The "offset position" is the position in the file where the user-space code is reading or writing. When you do `echo "hi" > /dev/device_name`, you are writing to the beginning of the file, which is position 0. You could test writing to a different position from the command line by using, for example, `echo "hi" | dd of=/dev/device_name seek=2000`

Note: you need to update this *yourself*. If the user-space code writes 4000 bytes, you should increment *offset by 4000. Otherwise, if they write another 4000 bytes after that, *offset will still be 0 and they'll overwrite the first 4000 bytes instead of the next 4000.